# php-fpm error logging with nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, php-fpm

I have nginx+php-fpm on a server and the messages get truncated at 2048 chars, rendering the message quite unhelpful when a stack trace is logged : I can't see the following fields anymore:

- host (not interesting)
- upstream (not interesting)
- request (very very interesting)
- server (not interesting)
- client (not interesting, always 127.0.0.1 because of our architecture)

How do you overcome this problem? Do you change the format? Or did you find a way to overcome this stupid 2048 chars limitation which I hear is hardcoded? Or to disable this backtrace?

Comment: Have you tried increasing error max length? http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len

Comment: Yes, I tried that, I set it to 4096 chars in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, but nginx still truncates to 2048 chars

Answer (score 1):

It’s really hardcoded, you would have to edit the source file and compile nginx yourself. Have a look at the following file from the nginx source repository: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/trunk/src/core/ngx_log.h#L67

```
#define NGX_MAX_ERROR_STR   2048
```

Increase it to what suites your needs.