# php-fpm error log is trucated

Tags: nginx, php, logging, php-fpm

I'm setting up test environment where I have nginx and php-fpm on centos 7. I have successfully setup everything and I can run php code.

This is my configuration:

> nginx version: nginx/1.9.9
>
> PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2015 20:42:32) ( NTS )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>
> with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

My challenge is to get php error log. I've managed to enable `catch_workers_output = yes` but the errors are there. If error text is long it gets truncated.

My question is how to configure php-fpm to log all on stderr from child process?

Best regards

Comment: See docs http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Have you reviewed your `error_log` section of your php.ini? What values are you using?

Comment: I just found this: http://serverfault.com/questions/424532/php-fpm-error-logging-with-nginx?rq=1 Only solution is to recompile ... :(